# db2 sql scripts and newlines

Tags: sql, db2

Just getting started with db2. 
Quick question about giving it SQL commands from a file.

If I run:

```
db2 -f mySQLcommands
```

and all my commands are one line sql commands they execute with no problems. if I put newlines in the middle of my sql statements then db2 comes back with "expected such and such a character after"
Here is an example with new lines:

```
CREATE TABLE Example (
              id int)
```

If there was no newline it would run.  I tested quickly in nano, so that means it's using the \n character probably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the -t command line switch to enable multi-line statements that are by default terminated with a semi-colon ;

e.g.

```
db2 -t -f mySQLcommands

CREATE TABLE Example (
              id int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative is to [use something like PyDB2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydb2/) and let Python manage the interface with DB2.

Something like this should do:

```
import pydb2

mysqlstmt = open('create_table_example.sql', 'r').read() # multi-line SQL is ok

conn = pydb2.connect(database="db", host="hst", user="usr", password="pswd")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute(mysqlstmt)

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()

mysqlstmt.close()
```

Comment: it has got to be a plain text sql file. Not my decision. :(

Comment: @Chris:  you can definitely read a query from a plain-text file and send to DB2 using the above method. afaik .sql files are plain-text.  i happily do things like this on a daily basis.